# I want the modal to open with the correct ID i.e. in the foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I have a problem: I used a `foreach` to list a database collection with a button to open a modal in each one. The button works correctly, but the ID that passes into the modal does not. If the modal code is inside the `foreach`, in all options the first id always appears, if it is outside the `foreach` the last ID always appears.

```
<div class="row">
    @if ($trainingphases == null)
        <p>null</p>
        @else
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card mt-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <!-- right control icon --> 
                        @foreach ($trainingphases as $trainingphase) 
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordionRightIcon">
                            
                            <div class="card ">
                                <div class="card-header header-elements-inline">
                                    <h6 class="card-title ul-collapse__icon--size ul-collapse__right-icon mb-0">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="text-default collapsed" href="#accordion-item-icon-right-{!!$trainingphase->id_trainingphases!!}"
                                            aria-expanded="false">{!! $trainingphase->title !!}</a>
                                    </h6>
                                </div>
                                <div id="accordion-item-icon-right-{!!$trainingphase->id_trainingphases!!}" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionRightIcon" style="">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                    <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" placeholder="teste" name="description">{{ $trainingphase->description }}</textarea>
                                    </div>                                                                              
                                </div>                                                                        
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">editar {!! $trainingphase->title !!}</button>
                            </div> 
                            </div>                               
                        </div>  
                                                      
                        @endforeach 
                        <!-- /right control icon -->                            
                    </div>                        
                </div>                   
            </div>                
        @endif
    </div>
         
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('create.trainingphase', array('id_trainings'=>$training->id_trainings)) }}">
                    @csrf
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="title" placeholder="{!! $trainingphase->title !!}" name="title"></h5>
                        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="descriptiom">Descrição</label>
                <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" placeholder="teste" name="description">{{ $trainingphase->description }}</textarea> 

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is logically right, if you need to do that correctly use js, as when the user click on button change the id in the modal to be the button id value

Answer (score 1):

**Explaination**

This is the expected behaviour of a loop within PHP.

So your code will evaluate from top to bottom and within your `@foreach` loop you are essentially re-assigning the value of `$trainingphase` within the scope of the script.

Once the loop is finished, the value of `$trainingphase` is not unset so it will be whatever the last value was in the object you had just looped through.

---

**Solution**

Keep the modal code outside of the loop and try using `data` properties on the buttons you are using to open the modal to pass values into the modal itself.

Documentaion on this can be found here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content